# Copying unknown length buffer to a fixed size buffer in C

Tags: c, struct, buffer

How can we copy an unknown size buffer into a fixed buffer in c?

For one of my functions, I'm trying to copy an unknown size buffer into a fixed buffer (of size 1024 bytes). The fixed size buffer is declared in a struct (Later I'll need to send all the content of the struct at once). I am unsure which function would be best to solve this issue.

I will send the struct buffer (ex_buffer) and reset the values in the struct buffer (ex_buffer); Then I need to store the next 1024 bytes from the unknown size buffer (buffer) into the fixed buffer (ex_buffer) and so on.

I've attached a small snippet of a general code for example purposes.

```
 struct example {
      char ex_buffer[1024];
 }

 int main (int argv, char *argv[]){
      char *buffer = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*1024);
      FILE *example = fopen(file,"r");

      fseek(example, 0L, SEEK_END);
      //we compute the size of the file and stores it in a variable called "ex_size"

      fread(buffer, sizeof(char), ex_size, example);
      fclose(example);

      //Now we want to copy the 1024 bytes from the buffer (buffer) into the struct buffer (ex_buffer)
      While( "some counter" < "# of bytes read"){
            //copy the 1024 bytes into struct buffer
            //Do something with the struct buffer, clear it
            //Move onto the next 1024 bytes in the buffer (ex_buffer)
            //Increment the counter
      }

 }
```

Comment: Please upload the actual example, you removed important parts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `memcpy()`, like this

```
memcpy(example.ex_buffer, buffer, 1024);
```

- Also, `realloc(NULL ...` you really should write `malloc()` instead.
- And, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: How would I go about copying every 1024 from buffer?
ie. copies from 0-1023 then 1024-2047 and so on?

Comment: Learn about pointer arithmetics. It's simple, you increment the pointer by the offset you need.

Comment: Okay perfect. One more question, When using memcpy() what should happen when I run into the case where we are at the end with say 45 bytes left. Would memcpy() just copy the 45bytes and pad the rest with NULL?

Comment: @Engah No, you should keep track of that yourself.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko No, that's c++ and this is c, they are not the same.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi it was tagged as c++ when I post my comment.